# How do you use interjections effectively in poetry?

Tags: creative-writing, poetry

How do you use interjections effectively in poetry? I am wondering when and where you can use the interjection O.

One thing I noticed is that O is often optional, and is used when we refer to a person or a thing.

> O, sweet princess, whose hair is finer than the finest silk

> whose eyes are deep as the high lapping seas

I am wondering if there are other use cases, and when we should use it and when we should avoid it.

Comment: Isn't this usually 'Oh' not 'O'? It's poetry, so really the question is, does it have the vibe you're looking to create? I tend to think of interjections as "If I put an exclamation mark after it, does it make sense?" Here, in your example, it seems to be there to add emphasis. Do you want that extra intensity, or is your vibe mellower and calm? Are you grabbing attention or is it more of a reflective soliloquy?

Comment: @DWKraus I think of 'O' as the older and "more poetic" version of 'Oh'

Comment: Eheu fugaces labuntur anni. -- Horace